# failing to use mvn package with twitter4j

Tags: maven, heroku, package, twitter4j

I am trying to deploy twitter4j project to heroku.

when I run the following command:

```
$ mvn package
```

this is what i get:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running twitter4j.auth.OAuthTest
Tests run: 15, Failures: 0, Errors: 15, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.072 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running twitter4j.AuthorizationTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationTest
Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.092 sec
Running twitter4j.DirectMessagesResourcesTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running twitter4j.FavoritesResourcesTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.004 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running twitter4j.FriendsFollowersResourcesTest
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 6, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.01 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running twitter4j.HelpResoursesTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.004 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running twitter4j.http.BASE64EncoderTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 sec
Running twitter4j.http.HttpClientTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running twitter4j.http.PostParameterTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 sec
Running twitter4j.internal.async.DispatcherTest

.
.
.

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.334 sec
Running twitter4j.internal.json.HTMLEntityTest
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.023 sec
Running twitter4j.internal.json.RateLimitStatusJSONImplTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.004 sec
Running twitter4j.internal.json.UserJSONImplTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.107 sec
Running twitter4j.internal.KryoSerializationTest
403 vs. 1522
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.042 sec
Running twitter4j.internal.util.ParseUtilTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 sec
Running twitter4j.internal.util.StringUtilTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec
Running twitter4j.ListResourcesTest
Tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Errors: 7, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.011 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running twitter4j.management.MBeansTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.014 sec
Running twitter4j.MBeansIntegrationTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.004 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running twitter4j.PagingTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 sec
Running twitter4j.PlaceGeoResourcesTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 3, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running twitter4j.SavedSearchesResourcesTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.004 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running twitter4j.SearchAPITest
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 4, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running twitter4j.SpamReportingResourceTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running twitter4j.SuggestedUsersResourcesTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running twitter4j.TimelineResourcesTest
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 5, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.007 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running twitter4j.TrendsResourcesTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running twitter4j.TweetsResourcesTest
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 6, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running twitter4j.TwitterExceptionTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 sec
Running twitter4j.TwitterTest
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 4, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.007 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running twitter4j.UndocumentedResourcesTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running twitter4j.UsersResourcesTest
Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 9, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.01 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running twitter4j.util.CharacterUtilTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 sec
Running twitter4j.util.TimeSpanConverterTest
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.024 sec
```

what am i doing wrong?

hope this was useful information..

Answer (score 0):

Typically error details are available under target/surefire-report. From there you can try to guess where the error came from, and consult twitter4j community maybe

If you want to cut the corner (might not be the wisest thing to do). You can skip the unit test by adding skip test flag

```
mvn package -DskipTests
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to **deploy** the twitter4j based application - you want to make sure that your unit tests pass first. You need to fix the tests to continue. That's a regular dev cycle.

If you still want to package the artifact ignoring any test failures - you may add the following property to the command line:

```
-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true
```

See maven surefire plugin documentation here: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html